# SQL Server query using multiple where clause

Tags: sql-server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFK7U.png)Hi all I have a sample table here

I'm using this query :

```
SELECT 
    PART_NUMBER, DATE, [WH-IN], [WH-OUT], [END-BAL] 
FROM 
    TABLE1 
WHERE 
    PART_NUMBER = 'TR131305R'  
    AND DATE <= '2016-05-30' 
    AND [WH-IN] = 'W1' 
    OR [WH-OUT] = 'W1'
```

The problem is that it also fetch the record that GREATER THAN the DATE 2016-05-30

Comment: The or trumps all.... what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your `OR` statement, it will grab any record that adheres to this clause:

```
PART_NUMBER = 'TR131305R'  
and DATE <= '2016-05-30' 
and [WH-IN] = 'W1'
```

or any record matching:

```
OR [WH-OUT] = 'W1'
```

Fix it with parenthesis:

```
SELECT PART_NUMBER, DATE, [WH-IN], [WH-OUT], [END-BAL] 
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE PART_NUMBER = 'TR131305R'  
and DATE <= '2016-05-30' 
and ([WH-IN] = 'W1' --wrap this clause in ()
or [WH-OUT] = 'W1')
```

Comment: Great! it helps a lot! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You need `parenthesis`

Currently your query `Where` clause will be processed like this

```
WHERE (PART_NUMBER = 'TR131305R' and DATE <= '2016-05-30' and [WH-IN] = 'W1')
or [WH-OUT] = 'W1'
```

Because `AND` has higher priority then `OR`. So use parenthesis to apply filter in proper order.

```
SELECT PART_NUMBER, DATE, [WH-IN], [WH-OUT], [END-BAL] 
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE PART_NUMBER = 'TR131305R'  
and DATE <= '2016-05-30' 
and ([WH-IN] = 'W1' or [WH-OUT] = 'W1')
```

or you can reverse `IN` operator

```
SELECT PART_NUMBER, DATE, [WH-IN], [WH-OUT], [END-BAL] 
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE PART_NUMBER = 'TR131305R'  
and DATE <= '2016-05-30' 
and 'W1' in ([WH-IN] , [WH-OUT])
```

Comment: Great! it helps a lot! Thank you so much!